# Table based on the month viewing in calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I had followed this question to create a table -> [Excel table in HTML throught Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768947/excel-table-in-html-throught-javascript)

My table is connected to a calendar created throught fullCalendar library and I implamented this table in a modal.
I also found a way to get the current visualized month as header of the table (by using getView). But now I have this bug:
**This is how my table show up the first time I open it (it's the correct viewing):** [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kOIX.png)

and this is how it shows up when I open it the second time, also in a different month: [wrong one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqpv2.png)

These are the mod I did to the code linked to the question added at the begining here:

```
function renderTable($targetTable, date, view, element ) { 
    
    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    var start = view.intervalStart._d;
    var end = view.intervalEnd.subtract(1, 'days');
    alert(end);
        
        
    //prende mese e anno attualmente visualizzati e lo imposta come titolo del modal nell'HTML
    const months = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"];
    
   //calcola il numero dei giorni nel mese (30/31/28)
   let numberOfDaysInMonth = new Date(end).getDate(); // just get the last day
    
   //create the table header to display the month and date, and make is span all the days + the names column + the total column.
   let $tableHeader = $(`<tr><th colspan="${numberOfDaysInMonth+2}" style="text-align: center;">${months[start.getMonth()]} ${start.getFullYear()}</th></tr>`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Basically where i call the function that build my table I added this:

```
    //table2 is the ID of my table
var table = document.getElementById('table2');

//i check if the table is empty; if it is than I render the thead and tbody
if (table.rows.length == 0){
    var date = new Date();
    renderTable($('#table2'), date);        
}
//if not, before I delete whats inside and than I render it
else if(table.rows.lenght != 0){
    $("#table2 thead").empty();
    $("#table2 tbody").empty();
    var date = new Date();
    renderTable($('#table2'), date);
}
```